# How can we configure IIS for domain name mapping

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting

I would like to configure IIS server at(windows server 2003) for domain name mapping.

We have purchased domain name for one of our newly created website. I would like to know how can i configure IIS so that anybody from outside world can reach wensite by typing url.

say http://xyz.com/ it should redirect at my website home page.

I have made website in using asp.net and oracle.

Please help me? If there is some tutorial/ link please forward me.

This is my first experience of hosting.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure your DNS settings for the domain you purchased so that the "A" record points to the IP address of your web server.

Then you need to configure a website on your IIS server and specify the host header which matches up to the domain name you purchased.

This tutorial should help: http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/